# fnmatch - single pattern to allow only text which have dots and digits

Tags: github, fnmatch

In GitHub I want to protect branches which have digits and dots. But if a branch has any letters, than it should not be protected

need `fnmatch` pattern so text with digits separated with dots will be matched

**matched** examples:

```
11.22
20.2
1.2.2.3.4
```

**not matched** examples:

```
abc_2.2

2.2_sss

1.9_AAA-1233
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this, that is if you must use `fnmatch`, is to repeat the pattern. Code is follows

```py
for i in range(1, 256): # github max branch name size 255
    fnmatch_pattern = '[0123456789.]'*i
    # whatever fnmatch function you want
    # append the result however you like. Note there will be duplicates
```

This is by far the best solution I can think of. Sorry if it's still so inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Try this :- '^[0-9.]+$' --> Regex

*?[0-9.?]+* --> fnmatch

Comment: your asnwer provides regex pattern, but fnmatch pattern is required.

Comment: added fnmatch .

Comment: thank you, unfortunately provided fnmath pattern does not match values from my matched example